# Can't get React Bootstrap button to span full width of column

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am using the React Bootstrap Container, Row and Column elements to layout a form that I have.

I have one row that contains 2 columns each with a button inside it. These buttons are generated from State.

I would like to have it so that the buttons span the whole length of the column they are in, so equal distant regardless of text they contain.

But can't work out how to do this. In the react bootstrap documentation it says that this should be possible by using the block attribute.

Below is my code.

```
//This is the state, the values for label are hardcoded for now, //but would be dynamic.

 state = {
        teamSelection: {
            teamAName: {
                elementType: 'button',
                label: 'Trail Blazers',
                selected: "true"
            },
            teamBName: {
                elementType: 'button',
                label: 'Warriors',
                selected: true
            }
        }
    }

//This generates the formElementArray to be used below.

 const formElementsArray = [];
        for (let key in this.state.teamSelection) {
            formElementsArray.push({
                id: key,
                config: this.state.teamSelection[key]
            });
        }

matchResultInputForm = (
            <Form >
                <Container fluid>
                    <Row>
                        <ButtonGroup>
                            {formElementsArray.map(formElement => (
                                <Col>
                                    <Button
                                        key={formElement.id}
                                        className="mr-1"
                                        color="primary"
                                        block
                                        size="lg"
                                        label={formElement.config.label}
                                        selectedteam={this.state.selectedteam}>{formElement.config.label}</Button>
                                </Col>
                            ))}
                        </ButtonGroup>
                    </Row>
                    ...
```

So currently the buttons do not span the full width of the column and are auto sized based on text.

I have seen that there a few other questions on here that are similar but the solutions to these do not work for me.

e.g, I tried changing the ButtonGroup to a div and using `<div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group">` but this didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this.

I changed the column to be outside the ButtonGroup and also used the d-flex built in class for ButtonGroup.

```
<Row>
    <Col>
    <ButtonGroup className="d-flex">
        {formElementsArray.map(formElement => (
                <Button
                    key={formElement.id}
                    className="btn-block mr-1 mt-1 btn-lg"
                    color="primary"
                    block
                    label={formElement.config.label}
                    selectedteam={this.state.selectedteam}>{formElement.config.label}</Button>

        ))}
    </ButtonGroup>
    </Col>
</Row>
```